# Problema con e.preventDefault JS

Tags: javascript, eventos, submit

el navegador sigue reiniciando con el submit a pesar de que está puesto el prevent default...no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Añado parte del código no creo que sea todo relevante...El evento esta enlazado al boton de submit y cuando pulsas se recarga.

Añado el html del formulario, no tiene mucha complicación pero si os sirve de orientación pues ahí va

```
    btnEnviar = document.getElementById('enviar');
    btnEnviar.addEventListener('submit',añadirCliente);
    

    function Conectar(){
        
        abrirConexion = window.indexedDB.open('idb',1)
        
        abrirConexion.onerror = function (){
            console.log('error al conectar');
        }
        abrirConexion.onsuccess = function (){
            console.log('conectado');
            DB = abrirConexion.result;
        }
    }


    function añadirCliente (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let validar = validarCliente();
        if (validar == true){
            console.log('validado')
        } else {
            console.log('no validado')
            return;
        }

        cliente={};
        cliente.nombre = inputNombre.value;
        cliente.email = inputEmail.value;
        cliente.telefono = inputTelefono.value;
```

```
<form >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputNombre">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputNombre" placeholder="Escriba el nombre">
                    
                  </div>

                <div class="form-group my-3">
                    <label for="email">Direccion de correo</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Escriba el correo electrónico">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">El email es único para cada cliente</small>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group my-3">
                    <label for="telefono">Número de telefono</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono"  placeholder="Escriba su numero de telefono">
                  
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group my-3">
                    <label for="inputNombre">Nombre de la empresa:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputNombreEmpresa" placeholder="Escriba el nombre">
                    
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-3 d-block m-auto" id="enviar">
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Porque no intententas usar la funcion directamente desde tu boton asi: <button onclick=añadirCliente()></button>

Comment: Revisa la consola, probablemente hay un error que impide ejecutar Javascript normalmente y no se está capturando el evento.

Comment: Agrega tu HTML para entender mejor, y observando tu código quieres evitar el evento por defecto de un formulario (submit) y se lo estas asignando a un botón con evento (click), por eso no funciona.